# Question about returning pointers from functions

Tags: go

I wrote this test code:

```
import "fmt"

func getIntPointer(i int) *int {
    var result int
    result = i + 1
    return &result
}

func main () {
    ip1 := getIntPointer(4)
    ip2 := getIntPointer(10)
    fmt.Println(*ip1, *ip2)
    fmt.Printf("%p %p\n", ip1, ip2)
}
```

I expected to see:

```
11
11
address1
address1
```

Assuming the second call would use the same space for function variables (based on my C background where after a function stop its work all function variables that are placed in stack could be rewritten with the next function calls). But instead I got:

```
5
11
address1
address2
```

Why I've might be getting this results?
Why is this  difference with the expected output?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, no options required. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Why would you expect those values?
That behaviour is correct

Comment: About 30 years ago I learnt C and they told us that this is a wrong way, because after a function stop its work all function variables that are placed in stack could be rewritten with the next function calls.

Comment: Yes, but Go is not C. The compiler sees that the address of `result` is returned and allocates it on the heap right away.

Comment: Thank you, Marc, now it's clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is the result of escape analysis. The compiler detects that the variable `result` escapes the function, so is it allocated on the heap. That's why each call to `getIntPointer` returns a new `result` pointer. The function is equivalent to:

```
func getIntPointer(i int) *int {
    result:=new(int)
    *result=i+1
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so it is a smart compiler feature. ;)